# Xamarin, Objective C or Phonegap Which one is better?

Tags: iphone, development-environment

I am new to iPhone development. There is a new project coming up. Please let me know which is the best among Xamarin, Native Objective C development or Phonegap for iPhone development. Is there any good Objective C framework available in that allows faster development?

Answer (score 1):

If you already know csharp and you like it, I suggest you to try Xamarin tools. With Xamarin.Forms you can also write cross platforms apps with only one code. 
If you know objective c or swift, and you like it, continue wit it if you don't have to do a cross platforms app. I left html5 at the end.